# super() end of the line stopper

Tags: python

I have just been watching the [Super considered super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) talk by Raymond Hettinger.  In it, he describes how `super()` calls the next class in line.  He demonstrates this visually by using the `help()` method which shows method resolution order.

Towards the end of the talk he describes the need for a super stopper class at the end of the method resolution line.  I've googled this term and found nothing so am unclear exactly what he means here - how does this stopper class work in practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply the method in the chain that *doesn't* use `super()` to call the next method. Usually these are on the base class in the hierarchy.

After all, if there is no next method in the MRO chain to call, you'd get an error as there'd be no next method to look up in the first place.

Raymond states this quite explicitly; transcripting from the video:

> You put a stopper object at the end; *not* `object`, you can create an object, call it `Root`, and put it in, and all it is something that has the method of interest; pass it along but doesn't actually call `super()`. Somebody at the end of the chain shouldn't call `super()`.

Comment: Ah ok, seems obvious now you put it like that.  I thought i might have been missing something, thanks!